# Alternate To REPLACE

Tags: sql

I am using `REPLACE` statement to replace certain string in my column.

```
update USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS
set DefaultValue = replace(DefaultValue, 'Area', 'Area_123')
```

It works fine most of the times. But If I have `Area` and `Area_Description` data in my `DefaultValue` column, it replaces both to `Area123` and `Area_123_Description`.

`Area` and `Area_Description` are different. I want to replace just `Area` and not `Area_Description`.

Sample Data

```
Sno     DefaultValue
1       Area
2       Area_Description
3       Area123
4       Equipment
5       Equipment_Name
```

Of all the above values only first row i.e DefaultValue=Area should change to Area123. Rest all should not change.
Also i cant put a where clause like WHERE DeaultValue='Area' in my replace statement as I need this to work for all other scenarios like Equipment or any other.

Comment: It might be clearer exactly what you mean if you could add some sample data (including some rows where no replacement should happen, some where it should and some where it's currently problematic) and your expected results.

Comment: But, if I'm understanding your example correctly, this sort of problem is arising because you're stuffing multiple pieces of data into a single column. Broken data models always makes for challenging queries.

Comment: Can "Area" (the part that must be replaced) be in the string multiple times?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes @Andre am using SQL

Comment: You should update your question showing every use case rather than forcing us to guess and make assumptions.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it requires to know in advance which texts NOT to replace. Can you come up with specific logic to identify when to replace it and when not, and put it in your question? I guess at least when not followed by a number or an underscore, maybe more rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `WHERE` condition to your `UPDATE` query to restrict the replacement to only occurrences where the `DefaultValue` column begins or ends with `Area`, or contains `Area` as a standalone word.

```
UPDATE USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS
SET DefaultValue = REPLACE(DefaultValue, 'Area', 'Area_123') 
WHERE DefaultValue LIKE 'Area' OR
      DefaultValue LIKE 'Area ' OR
      DefaultValue LIKE ' Area ' OR
      DefaultValue LIKE ' Area'
```

Comment: maybe better WHERE DefaultValue NOT LIKE '%Area_123%'

Comment: @gsharp I was considering this approach, but then I thought that perhaps there could be other false positive cases besides the one shown.  I'm assuming there are no false positives which involve whitespace surrounding the word `"Area"`.

Comment: @Tim thanks for the reply. But my column can contain values like "Area--Area_Description"    I want to edit this column value to Area123--Area_Description

Comment: If you need a complex regex (you do), then it is going to be more work.  You can't solve this with basic regex.

Comment: I think I can work out with this solution. I have added spaces to the default value column data where ever i need it to update. Thus only those values are getting updated that have spaces.

Comment: @Tanu If you update showing all the contexts which you want to replace I can also update my answer.

Comment: @Tim Its simple I want to replace Area(not always although am using Area just as an example my application decides what to replace on run time). 'Area' should replace to Area123. Area_Description,Area123 should not get replaced. see the sample data only first row should get updated

Comment: But you told us the column might contain something like `Area--Area_Description`.  Why did you omit this critical information?

Answer (score 0):

On `oracle` 11g and above.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Area Area_Description',
                      '(^|[^[:alnum:]_])Area($|[^[:alnum:]_])',
                      '\1Area_123\2') "Area"
FROM DUAL;
```

Results in:

```
Area
-------------------------
Area_123 Area_Description
```

Comment: Do we know that he is using Oracle 11g?

Comment: No we don't but as it is a *generic* question, this answer could be *useful* for `oracle` users.

Comment: Agreed.  And with the power of a regex function his question is more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the hell of it, I think this should work to replace only areas not flanked by letters, digits or underscores - change the pattern for other rules:

```
--Ends with
UPDATE USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS SET DefaultValue = 
SUBSTRING(DefaultValue, 1, LEN(DefaultValue) - LEN('Area')) + 'Area123'
FROM USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS
WHERE DefaultValue LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9_]Area'

--Starts with or equals
UPDATE USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS SET DefaultValue = 
'Area123' + SUBSTRING(DefaultValue, LEN('Area') + 1, 9999999999)
FROM USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS
WHERE DefaultValue LIKE 'Area[^A-Za-z0-9_]%'
OR DefaultValue = 'Area'

--In the middle - potentially multiple times
DECLARE @rowCount int SET @rowCount = 1
WHILE(@rowCount > 0)
BEGIN
UPDATE USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS SET DefaultValue = 
    SUBSTRING(DefaultValue, 1, PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9_]Area[^A-Za-z0-9_]%', DefaultValue)) + 
    'Area123' + 
    SUBSTRING(DefaultValue, PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9_]Area[^A-Za-z0-9_]%', DefaultValue) + 1 + LEN('Area'), 9999999999)
FROM USER_DEFINED_DATA_SETS
WHERE DefaultValue LIKE  '%[^A-Za-z0-9_]Area[^A-Za-z0-9_]%'
SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```